# Bootstrap 5 popover loading with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, popover

I'm trying to load a Bootstrap popover via AJAX.  The popover seems to load but the popover body shows as `[object Object]`. Below is my code. I trigger the popover on hover (link).

```
    $(".jtxndtl").popover({
        delay: 500,
        content: function () {
            var elem = $(this);
            url = elem.data('link');
            return $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                var resp = data.msg;
                var dtl = `<table class="border">  <tr><th>Date</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Payee</th>
                                <th>Outflow</th>
                                <th>Inflow</th>
                            </tr>`;

                $.each(resp, function (key, value) {
                    dtl += `<tr>
                                <td>`+ value['event_date'] + `</td>
                                <td>`+ value['description'] + `</td>
                                <td>`+ value['payee'] + `</td>
                                <td>`+ value['dr_amount'] + `</td>
                                <td>`+ value['cr_amount'] + `</td>
                            </tr>`;
                });
                dtl += "</table>";
                // console.log(dtl);
                return dtl;
            });
        }
    });
```

As you can see, I'm trying to load a formatted table in the popover. The table values populate correctly in the `console.log(dtl)` but the data does not show in the popover as intended.

I tried the numerous solutions posted here (very few for BS5) but none seem to work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi , see if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vh91kqro/) example works for you .